# How can I map the ñ key on the Helix text editor?

Tags: toml, helix-editor

I opened `./helix/config.toml` to set some keymaps and since I am a spanish speaker I wanted to add a functionality to the ñ key.

I added the following configuration:

```ini
[keys.normal]
ñ = "move_char_right"
```

When I tried to reopen Helix it said the following:

```
Bad config: unexpected character found: `\u{f1}` at line 13 column 1
Press <ENTER> to continue with default config
```

I tried to reference it with both UFT and hex and none of them seemed to work (probably because the keys were set as an Enum or a Struct). So here I am asking.

Comment: On [keys.normal] I tried to map the 'ñ' key just by typing ñ = "move_char_right"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the TOML syntax: To use characters other than ASCII letters, digits, underscores, or dashes in keys, the key itself needs to be in quotes.

```ini
[keys.normal]
"ñ" = "move_char_right"
```

See "bare keys" and "quoted keys" in https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#keys. Quoting from there, but omitting examples:

> **Bare keys** may only contain ASCII letters, ASCII digits, underscores, and dashes (`A-Za-z0-9_-`). Note that bare keys are allowed to be composed of only ASCII digits, e.g. 1234, but are always interpreted as strings.
>
> **Quoted keys** follow the exact same rules as either basic strings or literal strings and allow you to use a much broader set of key names. Best practice is to use bare keys except when absolutely necessary.